# Optimize LIMIT the number of rows to be SELECT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit, rdbms

Consider a table Test having 1000 rows

Test Table

```
id   name desc
1    Adi  test1
2    Sam  test2
3    Kal  test3
.
.
1000 Jil test1000
```

If I need to fetch, say suppose 100 rows(i.e. a small subset) only, then I am using the `LIMIT` clause in my query

```
SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 100;
```

This query first fetches 1000 rows and then returns 100 out of them.

Can this be optimized, such that the DB engine queries only 100 rows and returns them

(instead of fetching all 1000 rows first and then returning 100)

---

The reason for the above supposition is that the order of processing will be

- FROM
- WHERE
- SELECT
- ORDER BY
- LIMIT

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do Relational Databases Work Under the Hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886134/how-do-relational-databases-work-under-the-hood)

Comment: "This query first fetches 1000 rows and then returns 100 out of it." Why do you think that? What justification do you have? No DBMS would do that.

Comment: Check the `EXPLAIN` plan for your exact query, it may be that MySQL is _not_ iterating over the entire table but rather just keeps the "first" 100 records it encounters.  If you do have a certain order in mind, then add an `ORDER BY` clause along with an appropriate index.  This should be very fast.

Comment: @philipxy I suppose order of processing is  FROM -->  WHERE --> SELECT   --> ORDER BY -->   LIMIT

Comment: @philipxy Sort of.  If an `ORDER BY` clause were present, but no index could be used, then the database would have to sort all 1000 records, and then return 100 (according to some logic or rule).

Comment: What you "suppose" is no reason to think anything & no justification for anything.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen We only have the question, not some other question.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] "the order of processing will be" Again, no, and why do you claim that?

Comment: @philipxy reason for my supposition https://www.sisense.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations/

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please put everything needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. PS Reading web posts is not reasonable "research", read authoritative manuals & published presentations. PS That blog is poorly written, but it is trying to say that actual execution is NOT in the order that is used to describe the language: "SQL query planners can do all sorts of tricks to make queries run more efficiently, but they must always reach the same final answer as a query that is executed per the standard SQL order of execution." I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine LIMIT ROW COUNT with an ORDER BY, This causes MySQL to stop sorting as soon as it has found the first ROW COUNT rows of the sorted result.
Hope this helps, If you need any clarification just drop a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The query you wrote will fetch only 100 rows, not 1000.  But, if you change that query *in any way*, my statement may be wrong.

`GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are likely to incur a sort, which is arguably even slower than a full table scan.  And that sort must be done before seeing the `LIMIT`.

Well, not always...

```
 SELECT ... FROM t ORDER BY x LIMIT 100;
```

together with `INDEX(x)` -- This *may* use the index and fetch only 100 rows from the index.  BUT... then it has to reach into the data 100 times to find the other columns that you ask for.  UNLESS you only ask for `x`.

Etc, etc.

And here's another wrinkle.  A lot of questions on this forum are "Why isn't MySQL using my index?"  Back to your query.  If there are "only" 1000 rows in your table, my example with the `ORDER BY x` won't use the index because it is faster to simply read through the table, tossing 90% of the rows.  On the other hand, if there were 9999 rows, then it would use the index.  (The transition is somewhere around 20%, but it that is imprecise.)

Confused?  Fine.  Let's discuss one query at a time.  I can [probably] discuss the what and why of each one you throw at me.  Be sure to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the full query, and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`  That way, I can explain what EXPLAIN tells you (or does not).

Did you know that having both a `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` may cause the use of *two* sorts?  EXPLAIN won't point that out.  And sometimes there is a simple trick to get rid of one of the sorts.

There are a lot of tricks up MySQL's sleeve.